# Checking if section body was empty

Tags: sectioning

I want to create a command similar to `\@startsection` from LaTeX kernel. I need to start new page if the previous body had something and not do it if it was empty.

I looked into kernel documentation, but I don't understand how `\@noskipsec` works.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtoggle{emptybody}
\settoggle{emptybody}{true}

\newcommand{\mytitle}[1]{%
    \iftoggle{emptybody}{\textbf{#1}}{\clearpage \textbf{#1}}\par
}

\begin{document}

    \mytitle{First title}
    
    \mytitle{Should be on the same page}
    
    Text
    
    \mytitle{Should be on the new page}

\end{document}
```

Red line marks where pagebreak should appear[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mytitle}[1]{%
    \ifbool{@nobreak}{\textbf{#1}}{\clearpage \textbf{#1}}\par\nobreak\@afterheading
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

    \mytitle{First title}

    \mytitle{Should be on the same page}

    Text

    \mytitle{Should be on the new page}

\end{document}
```